# Lewis in chemformula

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

[image: Added image]I want to create a picture representig a chloroethane molecule having all lone pairs on chlorine, also if possible, to create an arrow which transfers C-Cl bonding pair only on chlorine.

Code done so far:

```
\schemestart[0,2.0,thick]
\chemfig{
           % 1
     -[:60]% 2
              (
              -% 3
              )
    -[:120]Cl% 4
}
\arrow{}
\chemfig{
          % 1
    -[:60]\mcfaboveright{C}{H}{^{\mcfplus}}% 2
         -% 3
}
\schemestop
```

English is not my first language.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code. You may add an image of the desired result as well to make the question more clear for people not into chemistry.

Comment: Your code doesn't even use the package `chemformula`. Are you sure your question isn't rather about `chemfig`? And where are `\mcfaboveright` and `\mcfplus` defined?